# Local language not supported in Dynamic inline SQL query (dynamically not able to add N before the local language columns)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, nvarchar

Table Name : Customer

```
customerID VARCHAR(20),
CustomerName NVARCHAR(100)
City NVARCHAR(100)
Country NVARCHAR(100)
```

CustomerName,City,Country columns will have local languages.

For Search functionality we need to form dynamic Query like below ,

```
SELECT CostomerID 
FROM customer
 WHERE CITY=N'New York'
```

So in SP we have code like below,

```
SET Query= 'SELECT CostomerID FROM customer WHERE ' + @columnName + '=' + @Value
```

exec Query

The Problem is Since City Column have local language we need to add N prefix in the values dynamic query , but we are not able to add the N in the dynamic Query

Sample Code

DECLARE @columnName NVARCHAR(200)
SET @columnName='CITY'

Expected
DECLARE @Value1 NVARCHAR(200)
SET @Value1=N'சென்னை'
PRINT(@Value1)
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(500)
SET @statement= 'SELECT CostomerID FROM customer WHERE ' + @columnName + '=N'''  + @Value1 +''''
PRINT (@statement)

Autual
DECLARE @Value2 NVARCHAR(200)
SET @Value2='சென்னை'
PRINT(@Value2)
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(500)
SET @statement= 'SELECT CostomerID FROM customer WHERE ' + @columnName + '=N'''  + @Value2 +''''
PRINT (@statement)

Tried
DECLARE @Value3 NVARCHAR(200)
SET @Value3='N'+'சென்னை'
PRINT(@Value3)
DECLARE @statement NVARCHAR(500)
SET @statement= 'SELECT CostomerID FROM customer WHERE ' + @columnName + '=N'''  + @Value3 +''''
PRINT (@statement)

Comment: Use a parameterized query with proper data types.

Comment: You gave your expected output at the end but not the actual output

Answer (score 0):

When you build your statement you aren't doing anything to put quote marks around the string literal that is supposed to be the value to look for.
You didn't say what you actually got but I expect it is something like:

```
SELECT 1 FROM customer WHERE City=Nசென்னை
```

If you expect to get:

```
SELECT 1 FROM customer WHERE City=N'சென்னை'
```

you need to build the statement this way:

```
SET @statement= 'SELECT CostomerID FROM customer WHERE ' + @columnName + '=N'''  + @Value + ''
```

This will fail if @Value happens to contain single quote marks. A better way would be to define a function that takes a NTEXT value and returns the string literal representation with preceding N, surrounding quotes, and any internal quotes doubled (and anything else I've forgotten).

Comment: thank you .now the problem is                                                  
 DECLARE columnName NVARCHAR(200)
SET columnName='CITY'

DECLARE Value1 NVARCHAR(200)
SET Value1=N'சென்னை'   --- in real time when we set this value we dont get N *
PRINT(Value1)
DECLARE statement NVARCHAR(500)
SET statement= 'SELECT CostomerID FROM customer WHERE ' + columnName + '=N'''  + Value1 +''''
PRINT (statement)

Comment: when we set the value we wont get  N right ?     we can set only like this *  SET Value1='சென்னை' * .. here it self we are facing issue..  Assume that local description we are reading from one transaction table.